# Email service providers PHP filter

Tags: php, email

I want to make custom path for "gmail-hotmail-yahoo" users for example

```
<input type="email" name="email"/>
```

now I want simple PHP code to filter email service providers

> if my email is **HelloWorld@gmail.com**  go to /gmailuser path

example

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

if ($email == 'gmail email' ) {
    header('Location: /gmailusers');

   } elseif ($email == 'hotmail email') {
    header('Location: /liveusers');
} else {
 header('Location: /unknownusers');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find (without case) if the email contains the keywords you need to redirect your users:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (stripos($email, '@gmail.com') !== false) {
    header('Location: /gmailusers');

   } elseif (stripos($email, '@hotmail.') !== false) {
    header('Location: /liveusers');
} else {
 header('Location: /unknownusers');

}
?>
```

Comment: i want to upvote but idon't have 15 reputation so anybody vote him

Comment: @rekobeko Even if you can't upvote the answer yet, you can already accept it :)